# VS Code emmet enter behaviour

Tags: visual-studio-code, sublimetext3, emmet

When I type `.class` and use emmet I get:

```
<div class="class">cursor's here</div>
```

And when I press <kbd>enter</kbd> I get:

```
<div class="class">
cursor's here</div>
```

And I have to press <kbd>enter</kbd> again + <kbd>arrow up</kbd>+ <kbd>tab</kbd>, its so annoying!

Intead of (like in sublime):

```
<div class="class">
   cursor's here
</div>
```

Is there any way to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>

```json
"emmet.preferences": {
    "format.forceIndentationForTags": ["body", "div"]
},
```

Comment: When  I'm tryin to paste that line it says : "Edit in the right hand side editor~~". Should I just paste it on the bottom of right side editor?

Comment: Done, however it didn't work. It's strange cause I just checked VS Code on windows and it is working right away without any adjustments. 

Only on linux there is a problem

Comment: I cannot reproduce on Linux VM.

Comment: Worked, I just pasted it wrong first time, than you!